# Spring Boot Upgrade to Latest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Getting this below exception while upgrading the springBoot starter parent 2.1.1.Release.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.nbcuni.compass.title.TServiceApplication.main(TitleServiceApplication.java:34)

POM.xml
```

PFB, pom.xml which is having complete parent 2.1.1.Release and dependency Management as Brixton.SR5 version details

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.Release</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
        <springfox.version>2.6.0</springfox.version>
    </properties>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <!-- <version>Brixton.SR5</version> -->
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: If you're using springboot 2.1 you should really be on the Greenwich release train

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Brixton.SR5` is [from 2016](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/23/spring-cloud-brixton-sr5-is-available) and doesn't support Spring Boot 2 since it was released [in 2018](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/01/spring-boot-2-0-goes-ga). If it worked with Spring Boot versions below 2.1.1 it was by chance.

You need to upgrade Spring Cloud to something recent e.g. `Finchley SR2`.

Comment: But required spring-cloud-starter-eureka which is not there in other spring cloud,available only in Brixton.SR5

Comment: This dependency was renamed to [`spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client`](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.1.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_service_discovery_eureka_clients) in recent version of Spring Cloud (unless you mean the server which is `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`).

Comment: cool Let me check then do you have any reason to have Finchley SR2 eventhough we have latest Greenwich M3

Comment: Greenwhich is not officially released and supported. M3 means Milestone 3.

Comment: Could not transfer artifact com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org: Unknown host repo1.maven.org

Comment: it's reachable from here, looks like a problem on your end: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/repo1.maven.org.html

Comment: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:pom:Finchley SR2 in http://repo.spring.io/milestone/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestone-repo has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: You can try `mvn -U` to force update. If you have problems using Finchley.SR2 please open a new question once you check your network.

Comment: constructor org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManager(org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheWriter,org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration,java.lang.String...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185482/discussion-between-thiru-and-karol-dowbecki).

Answer (score 1):

> Brixton builds on Spring Boot 1.3.x
>
> Finchley builds and works with Spring Boot 2.0.x, and is not expected
> to work with Spring Boot 1.5.x.

Replace Brixton with Finchley. Add below dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

[Follow this link for details.](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)